# There will not be after school class tomorrow, will be?

Tags: articles, british-english, existentials, tag-questions, compounds

> There will not be after school class tomorrow, will be ?

Is this question grammatically correct ?

Answer (score 2):

The suffix, **..., will be?** is not grammatically correct; I would also hyphenate **after-school** and I would use **an** as a prefix to make the *after-school class* singular.

You may mean:

1. Will there be an after-school class tomorrow?
2. There will not be an after-school class tomorrow, will there?
3. There won't be an after-school class tomorrow, will there?
4. There will not be an after-school class tomorrow.

With the above sentences, #1 is the straightforward question; while #2 is asking in a way that makes it clear that the asker would prefer that there was *not* a class tomorrow; #3 simply uses the contraction of *will not* to *won't* to match less-formal speech patterns.  #4 is a statement, not a question.

If the concept of "an after-school class" is not common to your audience, then you can swap **after-school** and **class**:

- Will there be a class after school, tomorrow?
- There won't be a class after school, tomorrow, will there?
- There will not be a class after school, tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with -

> There will not be an after school class tomorrow. Will **there** be?
>
> Will there not be an after school class tomorrow?
>
> Will or will there not be an after school class tomorrow?

As mentioned in the first alternative, **there** completes the sentence. The sentence seems it is missing something which can completed as mentioned in first alternative. Or you can use the other 2 examples if you want to change the sentence a bit.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to explain a little why OP’s version is wrong or why chose these phrasings?

Comment: Done. I have edited the post. Please check it.